# radio button control

Tags: c#

I'm working in C# Express 2010 program and in one form I have a question that its answers are two radio buttons with two selections Yes and No. When the user chooses yes, another hidden question should appear to the user in the same form to let him/her answer it.then depending on the user's answer, if it is yes, then a formula will be calculated. if he/she answers No, nothing will be calculated.

Thank you.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should probably ask this question in chucks, you've basically asked how to make an entire program.  Try asking individual problems first.  This way, you will learn the subject better and people won't feel too overwhelmed with the question to answer you.

Comment: Hi Sarah! Welcome to stackoverflow. Have you tried anything? it would be easier if you can share the code that you have so far.

Comment: Is that a web or desktop application ??

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I should have written "CheckedChanged" not "Checked"**  Thanks, @Akram

You need to use the [RadioButton.Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked.aspx) event.

Then place your calculations and code to show the next question in the event handler.

**Addition Info:**
In your environment, click on the radio button on your form.  Then under the properties window, click on the Events tab (the one that looks like a lightning bolt) and go to "Checked".  Double Click on the evnt and the event handler will be stubbed out for you.

Comment: @AkramShahda Ha!  Sometimes I amaze even myself.

Comment: You are not alone .. Check the other answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle the [RadioButton.CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged.aspx) event.

---

Also refer to the following:

[RadioButton Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5hxcyah.aspx)

[RadioButton](http://en.csharp-online.net/RadioButton)

[Radio Button Control](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/2187/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `RadioButton.Checked`

```
private void YESradioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible; // to show your question 
}
```

and you can make :

```
private void NOradioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     label1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden; // to hide your question 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! but I tried it, but I got this error: The type or namespace name 'Visibility' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: the code was for wpf application if you work with winform you just have to make  label1.Visible = true; or false